# If values of multiple columns are equal in different dataframe sizes - R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes with two columns each, and I want to know how to create a vector with `1` when both values are in the other dataframe, or `0` where both are not.

```
x <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1),
                B = c(10,1,30,1,50,60,1,80),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y <- data.frame(C = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                D = c(1,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

vector <- ifelse(y$C == x$A & y$D == x$B, 1,0) # This works when both dataframe are the same size.
```

It works when the dataframe is the same size, but when it isn't, I can't use `%in%` as it assess if `A` is in `C` and if `B` is in `D`, when I'm trying to assess if A and B are in C and D at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1),
                B = c(10,1,30,1,50,60,1,80),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(key = paste0(A, B, "_"))
y <- data.frame(C = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                D = c(1,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(key = paste0(C, D, "_"))

vector <- ifelse(y$key %in% x$key, 1,0)
```

I think you are after the key relationship between the two data frames (e.g. that AB = CD). If so the above should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is the order of rows important at all ?

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- mutate(x, id=as.character(1:nrow(x)))
y <- mutate(y, id=as.character(1:nrow(y)))

xy <- full_join(y, x, by="id")

xy %>% mutate(result = ifelse(C == A & D == B, 1,0) 
                )
```

What do you expect should happen to rows in `y` that don't have a "match" on `x` ?

```
    C   D id  A  B result
1   1   1  1  1 10      0
2   2  20  2  2  1      0
3   3  30  3  3 30      1
4   4  40  4  4  1      0
5   5  50  5  5 50      1
6   6  60  6  6 60      1
7   7  70  7  7  1      0
8   8  80  8  1 80      0
9   9  90  9 NA NA     NA
10 10 100 10 NA NA     NA
```